# Where can I get the mod_wsgi.so file for apache2/module?

Tags: python, mysql, django, xampp, mod-wsgi

I've spent the past 3 days trying to install mod_wsgi. After finding out that it was a more complex process on Windows, I decided to do it with Linux, but I still haven't figured out how to install it into my Apache/Xampp server because I can't find any .so files in the latest release for mod_wsgi. My httpd.conf file is already configured and ready to load the module but for obvious reasons doing

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

yields

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.30-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
httpd: Syntax error on line 523 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Syntax error
on line 11 of /opt/lampp/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/module 
/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
```

because there's no file there.

So where do I actually get said file? I've seen some of them on older websites, but I'm reluctant to use them because of compatibility issues or those versions of the module having less features and fixes.

EDIT: I have also tried installing it through pip install command, but I get the following error

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-L3NBQK/mod-wsgi/setup.py", line 164, in <module>
        'missing Apache httpd server packages.' % APXS)
    RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.
```

which I can only believe is because Apache was installed under the xampp package, therefore the script isn't able to find the apache httpd server packages.

EDIT 2: I'm working on elementaryOS Loki, 64 bit architecture, Python 2.7.12 (11-1), and Apache included in XAMPP v5.6.30

Comment: Well, I've tried some like this
http://enkoding.blogspot.mx/2013/01/setup-python-for-web-in-7-steps-on.html
This one does have a link for the .so files, but they don't go over the 3.4 release if I'm not wrong.

The same site informs that it has moved to github, so I go there and download the latest release in source code in a .tar.gz file, in which I haven't been able to find a .so file.

Comment: The official github page itself redirects to http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ for installing directly into Apache.
This site tells me there are 2 ways of installing it, the first says "The first is as a traditional Apache module installed into an existing Apache installation. Following this path you will need to manually configure Apache to load mod_wsgi and pass through web requests to your WSGI application." and nothing more. The second one is by using pip install, which I have already tried and does not work for me.

Comment: And lastly, I've already seen a lot of those thousands of tutorials you mention; a lot of them are for Windows, OSX, and Linux, and each of these may also vary depending on the architecture(32 or 64), and each of these may also vary in the Python version, and each of these may also vary in the Apache version. I hope your head didn't spin as much reading this post than mine when realizing all the different scenarios for this issue. Not to mention, a lot of them seem to be for older versions of the module.

Comment: RuntimeError: The 'apxs' command appears not to be installed or is not executable. Please check the list of prerequisites in the documentation for this package and install any missing Apache httpd server packages.

Comment: Don't use XAMPP. My memory is that they do not provide the bits that allow you to build additional Apache modules to be used with it. Using the system Apache, system Python and system package for mod_wsgi is the easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Graham Dumpleton himself answered in the comments. (Thanks for the advice!)

> Don't use XAMPP. My memory is that they do not provide the bits that allow you to build additional Apache modules to be used with it. Using the system Apache, system Python and system package for mod_wsgi is the easiest.